# Maintaining Session using HTTPClient on a Rails Application

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, applet, httpclient

I have an applet that talks with a Rails Application.  I wish to maintain a user's session so that the applet's communication is recognized as part of a user's browsing session.  I use apache's HTTPClient to send the request but  the rails application does not recognize the request as part of the users session.

This is the code that I use to build the request, I pass in session_id variable and the HTTP_COOKIE variable as applet parameters:

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        Cookie httpCookie = new Cookie("localhost", "HTTP_COOKIE", http_cookie, "/", null, false);
        Cookie sessionID = new Cookie("localhost", "session_id", session_id, "/", null, false);

        HttpState initialState = new HttpState();
        initialState.addCookie(httpCookie);
        initialState.addCookie(sessionID);
        client.setState(initialState);

        PostMethod post = new PostMethod("http://localhost:3001/vizs/add");
```

Any suggestions would be great!

slothishtype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with the following code:

> String session_id_str = "6a7eec105k231g51bjd0655e638034f3";
>
> Cookie sessionID = new Cookie("127.0.0.1:3001", "_chatter_session", session_id_str, "/", null, false);
>
> HttpState initialState = new HttpState();
>
> initialState.addCookie(sessionID);
>
> client.setState(initialState);

The two problems were:

1) Not putting the port number in the url.

2) Specifying the wrong session id.  In this example the application is called chatter so the session_id is _chatter_session.  I add the session id to the applet as a parameter.